# Selenium + Python: Print the text attribute of an element

Tags: python, selenium, getattribute

I would like to navigate through a website, find an element and print it.

Python version: 3.10; Selenium Webdriver: Firefox; IDE: PyCharm 2021.3.2 (CE);
OS: Fedora 35 VM

I am able to navigate to the appropriate page where the text is generated in a *drop down menu*.
When I locate the element by CSS Selector and attempt to print it, the output does print the text "None".
I would like it to print the Plan Name which in this case is "**Dual Complete Plan 1**".
The element is not always present so I also need to catch any exceptions.

The relevant HTML code of the element I am trying to print:

```
<span class="OSFillParent" data-expression="" style="font-size: 12px; margin-top: 5px;">Dual Complete Plan 1</span>
```

More of the HTML code of the element I am trying to print (element I am trying to capture is below the fourth div):

```
<td data-header="Plan Name">
    <div id="b8-b40-l1_0-132_0-$b2" class="OSBlockWidget" data-block="Content.AccordionItem">
    <div id="b8-b40-l1_0-132_0-b2-SectionItem" class="section-expandable  open is--open small-accordion" data-container="" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true" aria-disabled="false" role="tab">
        <div id="b8-b40-l1_0-132_0-b2-TitleWrapper" class="section-expandable-title" data-container="" style="cursor: pointer;" role+"button" aria-hidden="false" aria-expanmded="true" tabindex="0" aria-controls="b8-b40-l1_0-132_0-b2-Content" EVENT FLEX
            <div id="b8-b40-l1_0-132_0-b2-Title" class="dividers full-width">
                    <span class="OSFillParent" data-expression="" style="font-size: 12px; margin-top: 5px;">Dual Complete Plan 1</span>
            </div>
        <div class="section-expandable-icon" data-container="" aria-hidden="true"
            ::after
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b8-b40-l1_0-132_0-b2-ContentWrapper" class="section-expandable-content no-padding is--expanded" data-container="" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="b8-b40-l1_0-132_0-b2-TitleWrapper"> 
        <div id="b8-b40-l1_0-132_0-b2-Content" role="tabpanel">
            <a data-link="" href="https://www.communityplan.com" target="_blank" title="Click for more information"> EVENT
                <span class="OSFillParent" data-expression="" style="font-size: 12px;">www.CommunityPlan.com</span>
            </a>
            <span class="OSFillParent" data-expression="" style="font-size: 12px:">Phone Number: 8005224700</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

My relevant Selenium code:

```
# Find the Plan Name & if present set it to the variable "Advantage"
        try:
            Advantage = (WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#b8-b40-l1_0-132_0-b2-Title > span:nth-child(1)"))).get_attribute("value"))
        except:
            pass

print('\033[91;46m', Advantage, '\033[0m')
```

I expect the output to be "Dual Complete Plan 1", which is what I see on the screen and in the HTML. Instead I get the following:

> None

Apparently the "Advantage" variable is being set to "None".
Why?
I can see the text "Dual Complete Plan 1" that I want to print in the HTML code above.
What am I doing wrong?
I feel like I need a primer on "get attribute"?

Comment: try adding `.text()` at the end:`EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#b8-b40-l1_0-132_0-b2-Title > span:nth-child(1)"))).text()`

Comment: @xtekky When I add ``.text()`` to the end of my code, ``Advantage = (WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#b8-b40-l1_0-132_0-b2-Title > span:nth-child(1)"))).text())``  I get an error code saying ``NameError: name 'Advantage' is not defined``

Comment: Maybe try to find the element with `(By.CLASS_NAME, 'OSFillParent')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the text `Dual Complete Plan 1` you need to use

`element.text`

or

`element.get_attribute("innerHTML")`

or

`element.get_attribute("textContent")`

Instead of `presence_of_element_located()` use `visibility_of_element_located()`

and following `css selector` to identify

`div[id*='Title'] > span.OSFillParent`

Or

`div.dividers.full-width > span.OSFillParent`

**Code:**

```
        try:
            Advantage = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id*='Title'] > span.OSFillParent"))).text
        except:
            pass
        print(Advantage )
```

Comment: Thank you for the canonical answer.  
If I right click on “Dual Complete Plan 1” on the webpage in Firefox and right click “inspect”, I see the ``<span class="OSFillParent" data-expression="" style="font-size: 12px; margin-top: 5px;">Dual Complete Plan 1</span>`` and when I right click on that and click Copy -> CSS Selector, I get ``#b8-b40-l1_0-134_0-b2-Title > span:nth-child(1)``. If I use that CSS Selector in your code, it produces the following error: ``NameError: name 'Advantage' is not defined.``.

Comment: I have a few questions: 1.Why does the CSS Selector copied when I Inspect the webpage not work? 2. How did you determine the CSS Selector was ``"div[id*='Title'] > span.OSFillParent"``?  3.Can you recommend a resource that explains how to determine the proper CSS Selector? 4. Can you recommend a resource that explains element.text and element.get_attribute("textContent") and element.get_attribute("innerHTML")?

Comment: You can learn css selector from here https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/css-selectors-in-selenium/

Comment: It seems copied css selector is dynamic that’s why it is failing. You need to identify element uniquely identified on the page and should not be dynamic.

Comment: I understand now. The CSS Locator I get by inspecting a webpage may not work if the element is dynamic. And you created the CSS Selector  ``div[id*='Title'] > span.OSFillParent`` by using the parent of the element that needed to be located: ``Parent_locator > child_locator``.
You created the Parent_locator portion by using  ``tag name of the HTML element[attribute_name = ‘attribute_value’]`` and you created the child_locator by using the class attribute as ``HTML tag.form-control`` where the HTML tag is  followed by a dot (.) and then the class value. Brilliant.